# Не переходит по ссылке внутри сайта на удалённом сервере(GitHub)

Tags: html5, github-pages, ссылка

Всем привет! На сайте, в меню("бургере") в разделе "о нас" сделал вторую HTML страницу и подключил её в основной HTML. На локальном сервере, то есть у меня на компьютере всё работает отлично. Как только загрузил сайт на GitHub при нажатии на кнопку "О нас" пишет ошибку 404. Что может быть, я новенький и только решил попробовать сделать несколько страничный сайт.

```html
<ul class="navigation__list">
  <li class="navigation__item">
    <a href="/menu/we/index.html" class="navigation__link">
      о нас
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Вот ссылка на репозиторий в GitHub](https://github.com/AlexeyGustav/Balloons/tree/master)

Comment: Спасибо большое! За отзывчивость, но я не совсем понял, этот метод.В итоге разобрался, нашёл на просторах интернета статью и исправил пути, статью про пути нашёл в MDN

Comment: Я ошибся, то о чем я писал возможно сделать только если вы используете возможность движка jekyll, но не в сайте на чистом html.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в написании путей. Надо было убрать первый слэш перед menu. Вот неправильный пример:

```
<a href="/menu/we/index.html" class="navigation__link">
```

А вот правильный:

```
<a href="menu/we/index.html" class="navigation__link">
```